# How can i put BorderLayout in CardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, cardlayout, border-layout

Question can be incorrect, but i don't know how to ask correctly. I am sorry for that.

**Here the problem:**

My JFrame has `CardLayout` as the `layout manager`.
I have three `JPanel`'s and I switching between them. Everything was good until i had to add 2 `JPanel`'s into one of them. Now one of my `JPanel`'s should include two another `JPanel`'s. I read somewhere that it is posible. So this `JPanel` should have `BorderLayout`. There how it should be:
[image]

**Here is what i had before:**

- my `JFrame` class:

  ```
  public class JavaGame2 extends JFrame {

      public JavaGame2(){

          CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();
          setLayout(layout);
          GameController controller = new CardLayoutGameController(getContentPane(), layout);

          gamePanel = new GamePanel(controller);          
          menuPanel = new MenuPanel(controller);
          lvlPanel = new LvlEndPanel(controller);

          add(gamePanel, CardLayoutGameController.GAME_PANEL);
          add(menuPanel, CardLayoutGameController.MENU_PANEL);
          add(lvlPanel, CardLayoutGameController.LEVEL_PANEL);


          controller.showMenu();
  }
  ```
- `CardLayoutGameController` which is switching all `JPanel`'s:

  ```
  public class CardLayoutGameController implements GameController {
      public static final String GAME_PANEL = "GamePanel";
      public static final String MENU_PANEL = "MenuPanel";
      public static final String LEVEL_PANEL = "LvlPanel";            

      private Container container;
      private CardLayout cardLayout;

      public CardLayoutGameController(Container parent, CardLayout layout) {
          container = parent;
          cardLayout =  layout;
      }

      @Override
      public void showMenu() {
          cardLayout.show(container, MENU_PANEL);
      }

      @Override
      public void showGame() {
          cardLayout.show(container, GAME_PANEL);
      }

      @Override
      public void showEndLvl(){
          cardLayout.show(container, LEVEL_PANEL);
      }
  }
  ```

Then I added two `JPanel` classes `InterfacePanel` and `GameMainPanel`(which should include this `InterfacePanel` and my old `GamePanel`)

**How it looks like now:**

**UPD** runable example:

- runable class:

  ```
  public class Mcve extends JFrame {

      private GamePanel gamePanel;
      private LvlEndPanel lvlPanel;
      private GameMainPanel gameMainPanel;


      Mcve(){
          CardLayout layout = new CardLayout();

          setLayout(layout);
          GameController controller = new CardLayoutGameController(getContentPane(), layout);

          gamePanel = new GamePanel(controller);  
          lvlPanel = new LvlEndPanel(controller);
          gameMainPanel = new GameMainPanel(controller,this.getContentPane());

          add(gamePanel, CardLayoutGameController.GAME_PANEL);
          add(lvlPanel, CardLayoutGameController.LEVEL_PANEL);
          add(gameMainPanel, CardLayoutGameController.GAME_MAIN_PANEL);
          controller.showMenu();

          setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          pack();
          setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          setTitle("JavaGame2");
          setResizable(false); 
      }
      /**
       * @param args the command line arguments
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) {
          EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  JFrame jgame = new Mcve();
                  jgame.setVisible(true);
              }
          });
      }
  }
  ```
- `GameController`:

  ```
  public interface GameController {
      public void showMenu();
      public void showGame();
      public void showEndLvl();
  }
  ```
- `CardLayoutGameController` :

  ```
  public class CardLayoutGameController implements GameController {
      public static final String MENU_PANEL = "MenuPanel";
      public static final String LEVEL_PANEL = "LvlPanel";
      public static final String GAME_MAIN_PANEL = "GameMainPanel";

      private Container container;
      private CardLayout cardLayout;   

      public CardLayoutGameController(Container parent, CardLayout layout) {
          container = parent;
          cardLayout =  layout;        
      }

      @Override
      public void showMenu() {
          cardLayout.show(container, MENU_PANEL);
      }

      @Override
      public void showGame() {
          cardLayout.show(container, GAME_MAIN_PANEL);        
      }

      @Override
      public void showEndLvl(){
          cardLayout.show(container, LEVEL_PANEL);
      }
  }
  ```
- `GameMainPanel` - includes 2 `JPanel`'s:

  ```
  public class GameMainPanel extends JPanel {

      private Container container;
      private GameController controller;
      private BorderLayout layout;

      private GamePanel gamePanel;
      private InterfacePanel interfacePanel;

      GameMainPanel(GameController contrl,Container parent){
          controller = contrl;
          container = parent;
          setFocusable(true);
          setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          getPreferredSize();

          gamePanel = new GamePanel(contrl);
          interfacePanel = new InterfacePanel(contrl);

          layout = new BorderLayout();
          setLayout(layout);
          add(gamePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
          add(interfacePanel, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

          addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                  public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                          requestFocusInWindow();
                  }
          });
      }

      @Override
      public void addNotify() {
          super.addNotify();
          requestFocusInWindow();
      }

       public void paint(Graphics g) {
          super.paint(g);
      }

      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(800, 600);
      }

  }
  ```
- `GamePanel` :

  ```
  public class GamePanel extends JPanel {

      private GameController controller;    

      public GamePanel (GameController contrl){        
          controller = contrl;

          addKeyListener(new GameAdapter(contrl));
          setFocusable(true);
          setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          getPreferredSize();        
          addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                  public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                          requestFocusInWindow();
                  }
              });
      }

      @Override
      public void addNotify() {
          super.addNotify();
          requestFocusInWindow();
      }

      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
          return new Dimension(650, 600);
      }

      @Override
      public void paint(Graphics g) {
          super.paint(g); 
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

          Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24);
          FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);
          g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          g.setFont(small);
          g.drawString("game",300,300);
      }

      private class GameAdapter extends KeyAdapter{

          private GameController controller;

          GameAdapter(GameController contrl){
              controller = contrl;
          }
          public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
              if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                  controller.showEndLvl();
              }             
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `InterfacePanel`

  ```
  public class InterfacePanel extends JPanel {

      private GameController controller;    

      InterfacePanel(GameController contrl){
          setFocusable(true);
          setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          getPreferredSize();
          setSize(150,600);

          addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                  public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                          requestFocusInWindow();
                  }
          });
      }

      @Override
      public void addNotify() {
          super.addNotify();
          requestFocusInWindow();
      }

       public void paint(Graphics g) {
          super.paint(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

          Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24);
          FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);
          g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          g.setFont(small);
          g.drawString("interface",10,300);
      }

      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

          return new Dimension(150, 600);
      }
  }
  ```
- `LvlEndPanel`:

  ```
  public class LvlEndPanel extends JPanel{

      private GameController controller;

      public LvlEndPanel(GameController contrl){
          controller = contrl;

          setFocusable(true);
          setBackground(Color.BLACK);
          getPreferredSize();           
          addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

                  public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                          requestFocusInWindow();
                  }
          });

          addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

              @Override
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                  if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                              controller.showMenu();
                      }                
              }
              @Override
              public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {                
              }
              @Override
              public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                
              }

          });
      }

      @Override
      public void addNotify(){
          super.addNotify();
          requestFocusInWindow();        
      }

       public void paint(Graphics g) {
          super.paint(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

          Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24);
          FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);
          g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          g.setFont(small);
          g.drawString("Level Panel",300,300);
      }

       public Dimension getPreferredSize() {        
          return new Dimension(800, 600);
      }
  }
  ```
- `MenuPanel`:

  ```
  public class MenuPanel extends JPanel{

      private GameController controller;

      public MenuPanel(GameController contrl){

          setFocusable(true);
          setBackground(Color.WHITE);
          getPreferredSize();
          controller = contrl;

          addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
                  public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
                          requestFocusInWindow();
                  }
          });

          addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

              @Override
              public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
              }

              @Override
              public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                      if ((e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
                          controller.showGame();
                      }
              }

              @Override
              public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {                
              }

          });

      }

      @Override
      public void addNotify() {
          super.addNotify();
          requestFocusInWindow();
      }


      public void paint(Graphics g) {
          super.paint(g);
          Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

          Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24);
          FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);
          g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
          g.setFont(small);
          g.drawString("Game Menu", 300,300);
      }

      public Dimension getPreferredSize() {        
          return new Dimension(800, 600);
      }
  }
  ```

**updend**

And when I launch this, I have just black frame. How can i fix this? What I did wrong?

Thanks in advance.

And Thanks for editing.

Comment: An actual [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would involve less guess work and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer updated. did i edited correct?

Comment: i think i have `keylistener` problems again

Comment: You code has a few "issues", see my update for a list of the main ones ;)

Answer (score 1):

You're controller defines `showMenu` as

```
public void showMenu() {
    cardLayout.show(container, MENU_PANEL);
}
```

But you never add anything with the name of `MENU_PANEL`

```
add(gamePanel, CardLayoutGameController.GAME_PANEL);
add(lvlPanel, CardLayoutGameController.LEVEL_PANEL);
add(gameMainPanel, CardLayoutGameController.GAME_MAIN_PANEL);
```

Either change the name used for `gameMainPanel` to `MENU_PANEL` or change the `showMenu` to use `GAME_MAIN_PANEL` instead

**Updated based on example code**

There's actually nothing wrong with your layout, the (main) problem is your `MenuPanel` `paint` method.  Where possible, you should avoid loading fonts in your `paint` methods, the process of loading a font can be time consuming, which is preventing your panel from been painted in a timely manner.

Instead, pre-load the font, maybe in the constructor, and apply it when you paint, for example...

```
public class MenuPanel extends JPanel {
    //...
    public MenuPanel(GameController contrl) {
        //...
        Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 24);
        setFont(small);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;

        g.setFont(getFont());
        FontMetrics metr = g.getFontMetrics();
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString("Game Menu", 300, 300);
    }
}
```

This goes for `LvlEndPanel`, `InterfacePanel`,  and `GamePanel` as well...

**Side notes**

- `addNotify` will no longer work the way you've got configured, as the components are only added once, instead you should rely on the `ComponentListener` (which you are).  A better solution would be to use [the key bindings API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) which allows you to overcome the focus limitions of `KeyListener`.
- Normally, you would override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`.  `paint` does a lot of work which is easily broken and other child components can cause issues when they repaint...

Comment: sorry, but i didn't add that i changed there( 
    `public void showGame() {
        cardLayout.show(container, GAME_MAIN_PANEL);        
    }`

Comment: Then a runnable example will be required

Comment: @KadymovMukhammed Yes, update your original question to include it

Comment: example works if i add `KeyListener` to `GameMainPanel` but i had to have listener in `GamePanel` not in `GameMainPanel`. `GamePanel` doesn't focus again

Comment: @KadymovMukhammed Use key bindings, don't rely on `addNotify`

Comment: i deleted `addNotify`, i use `ComponentListener`.